# HTML5 Gamepad API weird values

Tags: javascript, linux, windows, html, gamepad

Using this demo of Gamepad API: http://html5gamepad.com/, I see a weird behavior with a simple gamepad (SNES basic USB gamepad):

In a Windows system (Windows 10) shows axis 0/1 values of 0.003922/-0.003922 on idle (without axis pressed):

[image: HTML5 Gamepad API on Windows 10]

I think that this weird values is for a [basic gamepad](http://www.ebay.com/itm/2x-Super-USB-Controller-Nintendo-SNES-GAME-PAD-For-PC-Raspberry-Pi-3-RetroPie-/162370196893?hash=item25ce04959d%3Ag%3AQOgAAOSwtnpXkn2f) without high precision, but with same gamepad on a GNU/Linux system (Ubuntu) shows axis 0/1 values of 0.000000/0.000000.

Why ocurrs this behavior? OS-dependent? Windows drivers problem?

Comment: calibrate your pad ;) However, I think 0.4% inaccuracy is within the specs. I would round that value to something I can work with anyway, so this should not be a problem.

Comment: Done. I calibrate gamepad with windows calibrate gamepad tools (recommend me other tool?), but same results. I don't have problems but I like know because this difference on GNU/Linux and Windows...

Comment: It depends on the driver. I guess the linux driver does the rounding internally, while the windows driver passes the values as they are received via USB

Comment: I have this weird `-0.003922` value in Mac, windows, Android. I'm using Amkette Game console